# Hangfire recurring Job in Plesk website not working

Tags: c#, plesk, hangfire

I have the following setup in my C# MVC project, in the Global.asax.cs file:

```
 ////hangfire config
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
     .UseSqlServerStorage("ContextName", new SqlServerStorageOptions
     {
         CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
         SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
         QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
         UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
         UsePageLocksOnDequeue = true,
         DisableGlobalLocks = true
     })
     .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings();
 //.UseLog4NetLogProvider(); // this creates a bunch of logs that inflates the DB, only for testing purposes!
```

and this code which I tried tweaking around but I can't get it to work in production, locally it works fine.

```
BackgroundJobServer backgroundJobServer = new BackgroundJobServer();
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => MethodCalling(DateTime parameter), "0 8 * * *");
```

This does work Local but not when I publish this to my Plesk environment.
I tried as well with this:

```
RecurringJob.Trigger("Identifier here");
```

and of course having set the Identifier in the AddOrUpdate method but it triggers each time the site is browsed I think. I want it to run every day of the year at 08:00 AM.

Tried chaning the time:

`"00 * * * *"` 
set to run every hour, every day every month or even with the obsolete `Cron.HourInterval(int)` but it seems to be triggered whenever I browse the site or +-3 times a day if I don't browse it, seems like maybe the IIS recycling cycle maybe?

I also tried changing it to this:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(()=> MethodCalling(DateTime parameter));
```

When I check my database (using EF) I can clearly see that it runs but something is not configured properly but I don't know what.

ANY suggestions are welcome!
Thank you!
(NOTE: not using .NET Core)

Comment: https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html If you cannot follow this, give up Hangfire. It is not a framework to run in all conditions.

Comment: Hi and thank you, I will check with my hosting provider if they are willing to configure this that way in IIS and I will do my part in Backend. Will post feedback here. Meanwhile, can you present alternatives for this kind of requirement?

Comment: @LexLi, unfortunately my hosting provider doesn't want to implement this config on their side since it's shared resources ... I need a Managed VPS or an alternative logic that handles 1 recurring job each day ... I don't want to use a timer or a Task for this, I think it's overkill?! Can anyone advise me alternatives for this?

Comment: Then it is really your budget that prevents you from doing this from within ASP.NET. Consider external services such as Zapier, https://zapier.com/apps/schedule/integrations They can help trigger daily events, and then those events can be used to send requests to your ASP.NET app (effectively run the jobs you wanted).

Comment: @LexLi, it is a simple website where people can subscribe to Yoga classes (no payments online) and maybe it will have 100visitors a month top. So yes budget is a part of the decision here. Isn't that similar to Microsoft Flow (zapier)?

Comment: Should be similar I think, but Zapier has some free quota.

Comment: @LexLi, thank you. I will take a look and either go with something like this, which will call my function trough API request or have some logic and a timer/task.

Comment: @LexLi, you can post an answer if you want, ill accept it. I just implemented an API in my project which accepts certain requests that trigger my function, along with zapier (BIG thank you for that, much better than Ms Flow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's rephrase the issue based on the discussion above. You want a daily trigger to initialize some tasks, and would like to know what can be the options when your solution is deployed to a shared hosting platform.

IIS/ASP.NET/ASP.NET Core is not designed for such tasks, and on a shared hosting platform you won't be able to trigger daily jobs without hurdles.

Therefore, the best option is to find an external resource (like Zapier) as the daily trigger, and let it call your web app to initialize the jobs.